# Including a conditional array in a PHP class definition

Tags: php, class

Ok I am trying to edit another developers PHP class definition to include a conditional array but it doesn't seem to be working.  Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?  I am attempting to make the substring search environmentally aware and have definted server_environment variables on the respective sandbox/dev/test/prod servers.

```
class ArrayStringReplacement {

    private $returnString = NULL;

    private $thisArray = '';

    function __construct($buff){
        if($_SERVER['SERVER_ENVIRONMENT'] == 'sandbox') {
            $thisArray = array(
                'www.infousa.com'   => 'localhost/IUSA-CMS',
                'www.infocanada.ca' => 'dev.infocanada.ca',
                'www.americanchurchlists.com'   => 'virintwebd01:2020',
                'publicfiling.infousa.com'  => 'Virintwebd01:2006',
                'ca.infousa.com'    => 'devca.intra.infousa.com',
                'leads.infousa.com' => 'devleads.intra.infousa.com',
                'orders.infousa.com'    => 'devorders.intra.infousa.com',
                'https://account.infousa.com'   => 'http://devaccount.intra.infousa.com',
                'https://shared.sub.infousa.com'    => 'http://virintsvcd01:2002'
            );
        } elseif ($_SERVER['SERVER_ENVIRONMENT'] =='dev') {
            $thisArray  = array(
                'www.infousa.com'   => 'dev.intra.infousa.com',
                'www.infocanada.ca' => 'dev.infocanada.ca',
                'www.americanchurchlists.com'   => 'virintwebd01:2020',
                'publicfiling.infousa.com'  => 'Virintwebd01:2006',
                'ca.infousa.com'    => 'devca.intra.infousa.com',
                'leads.infousa.com' => 'devleads.intra.infousa.com',
                'orders.infousa.com'    => 'devorders.intra.infousa.com',
                'https://account.infousa.com'   => 'http://devaccount.intra.infousa.com',
                'https://shared.sub.infousa.com'    => 'http://virintsvcd01:2002'
            );
        } elseif ($_SERVER['SERVER_ENVIRONMENT'] =='test'){
            $thisArray  = array(
                'www.infousa.com'   => 'test.intra.infousa.com',
                'www.infocanada.ca' => 'test.infocanada.ca',
                'www.americanchurchlists.com'   => 'testacl.intra.infousa.com',
                'publicfiling.infousa.com'  => 'testpf.dmz.infousa.com',
                'ca.infousa.com'    => 'testca.infousa.com',
                'leads.infousa.com' => 'testleads.intra.infousa.com',
                'orders.infousa.com'    => 'testorders.infousa.com',
                'account.infousa.com'   => 'testaccount.intra.infousa.com',
                'shared.sub.infousa.com'    => 'testshared.intra.infousa.com'
            );
        }

        $this->returnString = $buff;
    }

    public function processArray() {
        foreach($this->thisArray as $k => $v) {
            $this->returnString = str_replace($k, $v, $this->returnString);
        }

        return $this->returnString;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem/error messages do you get?

Comment: You define three options for `$thisArray`, but you never actually use it? You might benefit by putting `$this->thisArray = $thisArray;` at the end of the `__construct()` function. Or replace all instances of `$thisArray` with `$this->thisArray`

Comment: It just appears to fail in localhost/sandbox.  I am not getting any specific error and haven't tried pushing to any of the other environments yet.

Comment: Well thank you scrowler.  Adding $this->thisArray = $thisArray; at the end of the __construct() worked just fine.
I'll gladly give you credit for the answer if you make it an answer.

Comment: setup some debugging. xdebug will find this real quick.